# Is there a batch script to add users to the group power users?

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-xp

I am trying to create a script that will create new user accounts on new systems that we install and put them in the respective permission groups. I have managed to add users to the 'administrators' group and remove them from the 'users' group but I am having some trouble when it comes to adding users to the 'Power Users' and 'Remote Desktop Users' groups. The script so far is as follows:

```
net user User1 User1 /add

net user User2 User2 /add 

net localgroup administrators User2 /add

net localgroup powerusers User1 /add

net localgroup users Users2 /delete
```

Every thing bar the 4th line of the script is executing fine I have try'd the following lines to replace the 4th line and had no luck the lines are as follows:

```
net localgroup power_users user1 /add

net localgroup power%20%users user1 /add
```

Any help on this matter would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
net localgroup "Power Users" User1 /add
```

Answer (score 2):

*net localgroup*

lists the available groups in the machine .. Check if the group exists and then proceed with the addition.

If the group exists and u still have a problem try "Power Users" .